# JPA-style Criteria/CriteriaBuilder queries from Hibernate Session

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

I have an application that uses Hibernate 4.x, and it is currently using the native Hibernate APIs (meaning that I have a `SessionFactory` and `Session`s). I just [noticed](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch12.html) that the existing Criteria API is deprecated in favor of JPA's (superior) Criteria API:

> Hibernate offers an older, legacy `org.hibernate.Criteria` API which should be considered deprecated. No feature development will target those APIs. Eventually, Hibernate-specific criteria features will be ported as extensions to the JPA `javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery`.

I don't want to have to convert my application over to using `EntityManager` directly (even though it's easy to get a Hibernate `Session` from there) because we have a large amount of custom Hibernate configuration logic that will need to be replaced. Despite that, I definitely want to start using the JPA Criteria APIs, since the old APIs are deprecated (and will presumably disappear at some random point in the future, if past Hibernate releases are any indication) and they also provide much better type safety.

**How can I use the new CriteriaQuery/CriteriaBuilder API, if I'm using SessionFactory/Session?**

Comment: How are you currently getting your sessions? Is it in a central location? If so you should be able to change that so that you get your sessions from an EntityManager such that you have access to the EM. The problem is that Session is used by EntityManager and not the other way around. But if you make your higher level use EntityManager and just get the Session from that (so you don't break old code) you will be better off.

Comment: It is in a central piece of code, but part of my concern is that we have a pretty complicated configuration system for getting Hibernate (programatically) configured and I'm not sure that I can replicate that with JPA. If Hibernate's Criteria is deprecated in favor of JPA's Criteria, but there is no way to access it from the Hibernate API, I would have expected that they would also deprecate the Hibernate configuration API (instead it looks like they are continuing to massively build out the Hibernate config API)

Comment: True but it doesn't seem like you can mix and match JPA and Hibernate in this way. Even if you get the CriteriaQuery instance without EntityManager you will need an EM to execute a query with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the same dilemma in our project.
The project is really complicated: 90% of entities are generated dynamically; there is implemented API level above Hibernate criteria API, heavy DAO and service layer, that is very wide used; our hibernate version is patched many times to support specific functionality (like `START WITH`/`CONNECT BY`, `ARRAY` type in oracle and so on); postgresql and oracle are used both, alternatively etc.

The new JPA API would be very useful for us. We need ability to use functions at Criteria API (not HQL) level (like `NVL/coalesce` for some sort of performance reasons, `substring`, `trim` and so on).
Moreover we need Hibernate Envers which is available only for "`EntityManager`" JPA implementation.

Unhappily according to our research result there is no ability to use JPA Criteria API from native Hibernate at all. Envers can not be used too.
The Hibernate project is continually evolving and gaining new features.
Migrating to new hibernate versions is very complicated task for us. And we are very concerned about inability to use many new features of new versions after migration and grow with this basic framework.

Therefore we consider two possible ways for us: use `SQLCriterion` with own implementation of `Expression`s (resolve column names with `CriteriaQuery` and translate to SQL) or migration to "`EntityManager`" / `CriteriaBuilder`. Second way looks like unavoidable. But the migration to JPA implementation brings many hidden problems which ruins our project.

If we'll choose migration and it will be useful, I'll leave here what problems we will struggle with in this activity.